# visual studio 2013 concurrency visualizer tool. How to determine core load balancing

Tags: visual-studio, data-visualization, visual-studio-2013, analyzer

I am using the visual studio 2013 concurrency visualizer tool extension and i am trying to determine the workload of each processor with regards to tasks/threads.  However, although there is a lot of data being produced, it seems slightly strange that there is no detailed data on core utilisation, only a CPU utilization graph which doesnt give me the info on a processes threads - just the main process.  Yes, there is the threads tab which gives details on the threads but no info on core allocation... and the cores tab only provides info on context switching.

I have also tried the windows performance analyser to try and build up the data but that seems a dead end as well.  Is there a way to get the data i need out these vs tools?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Concurrency Visualizer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329530.aspx

It provides graphical views of CPU utilization, threads, and cores, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

It used to be part of the profiler in VS, but for VS2013 it's available as additional addin: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/02/concurrency-visualizer-now-on-the-gallery-for-vs2013.aspx